# google-cloud-sql cannot get replication working

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I have followed this guide 4 times now. With 3 different workstations.
[https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/replication#replication-enabling]

I have one cloud-sql instance, I have two compute instances.

each gce instance its just ubuntu with a lamp stack.

the Cloud-Sql instance would be the master, and the to mysql instances on the GCE vm's would be the slaves.

when I use the command in the google cloud-sql guide I get this:

> macpro:~ Weatherman$ gcloud sql instances patch 
> --backup-start-time 01:00 This command will change the instance setting. The following body will be used for the patch api method.
>
> {'instance': '', 'settings': {'backupConfiguration':
> [{'binaryLogEnabled': False, 'enabled': True, 'id': ',
> 'startTime': '01:00'}]}}
> Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  n

now from reading that I can see its set to "false". But that is the EXACT command the documentation says to use....

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I removed the instance name's and id's from the command....the commands issued were 100% correct.

Comment: just to note, I get: "ERROR 1382 (HY000): You are not using binary logging" when I try to check the binary logs. let me know if any more information would help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies - looks like the documentation is incorrect. We'll get that fixed.

In the meantime, could you try the following command to enable binary log:

```
gcloud sql instances patch --enable-bin-log <instance name>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have been racking my brain all afternoon on this. Thanks again!

Comment: Where can I find some more detailed documentation for this? I would like to get a better understanding of the platform. I googled --enable-bin-log and amazingly enough, I received 0 results.

Comment: The --enable-bin-log option is specific to the gcloud command line tool. Under the hood, it means that the mysql binary log options will be set when the server starts: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html

Comment: That's what I mean, where can I find more documentation regarding cloud SQL? Had you not told me about --enable-bin-log, where would I have read about it? That's my point....other than you telling me, where would I have gotten that specific info from on my own. By say, reading documentation...

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/replication) that you pointed out earlier had the incorrect command. That's been fixed.